# Calculate instance count of data in list

Tags: excel

I have a worksheet with data like the following:

```
Name  Type
----------
Joe   A
Bob   B
Dave  A
Cindy A
Jason B
Aaron C
Jim   B
Carl  C
```

I would like to add a third column which displays the following:

```
Name  Type  Instance
--------------------
Joe   A     1  <-- 1st instance of type A
Bob   B     1  <-- 1st instance of type B
Dave  A     2  <-- 2nd instance of type A
Cindy A     3  <-- 3rd instance of type A
Jason B     2  <-- 2nd instance of type B
Aaron C     1  <-- 1st instance of type C
Jim   B     3  <-- 3rd instance of type B
Carl  C     2  <-- 2nd instance of type C
```

Any idea how to do this in Excel with a formula? I know I could filter the list and manually number the types, but I need to do it with a formula.

**Note that in reality there are more than 3 types.**

Comment: That works perfectly. Thank you! Could you add it as a solution and I'll mark it?

Comment: Please look at my formula. It addresses the question as you originally posted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the heart of my formula is this: `=COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B2)`. But the larger formula addresses your more complex problem of selecting from two different sheets in turn.

Note: I created this formula for you before you edited the question, and then after I posted it your edit appeared. This formula is designed to work in your scenario where you have three sheets of FANTASY FOOTBALL.

Here is the formula to use on Sheet3:

```
=CHOOSE(1--(B2="qb"),INDEX(Sheet2!B:B,COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B2)),INDEX(Sheet1!B:B,COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B2)))
```

Enter it into cell `C2` and then copy downward as far as you need.

**Edit**

Here is a shorter version that does the same as the long formula above:

```
=INDEX(CHOOSE(1--(B2="qb"),Sheet2!B:B,Sheet1!B:B),COUNTIF(B$1:B2,B2))
```